# Customize specific websites on chrome's new tab page

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome's new tab offers the 8 websites you like to visit. Unfortunately for one of the sites, 4chan.org, the main page is a directory, not somewhere I want to go. I would like the 4chan.org thumb to instead open to 4chan.org/u/, taking me directly there instead of the main directory where I would have to manually find /u/.

Anyone know how to make this happen?

Thanks.

Edit: I would like this to happen without totally destroying the new tab's default functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the top of my head: use [this](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi) extension and cusomize your new tab page.
It will remove your previous settings but you will have better control ever it. (and yes .. I've read the "edit" :P)

Comment: Thanks, this is the best new tab replacement yet. However it loses the auto thumbs, which is disappointing, but... I'll take what I can get, thanks!